# How can I use cookies while screen scraping?

Tags: java, android

I want to scrape data from PHP web pages that are behind a login page. How can make it so I log in only once and then be able to access data on the subsequent pages without logging in again?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure if you can do this in Android, but on desktop platforms, I just use QtWebkit to keep cookies set by the website I'm trying to scrape. If you can run a GUI-less version of the Android browser, I would try setting the fields for login using JavaScript and then access the DOM of the protected content using JavaScript or the Android SDK.

Comment: After login you must remember the session identifier (usually a cookie) and attach it to each subsequent request... the cookie is just a HTTP header field, so it should work by just using Android's HTTPClient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using [Android's HttpClient` library](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) built into the OS.  They will manage your cookies automagically by default.  To quote from their docs:

> Interface for an HTTP client. HTTP clients encapsulate a smorgasbord of objects required to execute HTTP requests while handling **cookies**, authentication, connection management, and other features. Thread safety of HTTP clients depends on the implementation and configuration of the specific client.